# Solve three linear systems simultaneously, using an augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

[image]

I have no idea how to start. Do I just get x1 x2 x3 x4 with b1, b2, and b3, then we use substitution method to get x1 x2 x3 x4? I don't really know ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the question asks you to augment the matrix $A$ with the vectors $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$. This is the matrix
$$
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & \mid & b_1 & b_2 & b_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
4 & 2 & 1 & -3 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & -1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 8 & -7 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$
Performing row reductions gives the reduced row-echelon form
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref X
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{251}{265} & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{9}{265} & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \frac{4}{265} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{342}{265} & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
This reduced matrix tells us about the solutions to the equations 
\begin{align*}
Ax &= b_1 &
Ax &= b_2 &
Ax &= b_3
\end{align*}
The solution to $Ax=b_1$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you see the solutions to the other two equations?

Comment: Oh, so Ax = b2 is the (251/205, 9/205, ...) and Ax = b3 is the (-1,2,1,-1). right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean to apply the standard procedure simultaneously to $b_1, b_2, b_3$ to get  the three solution(s). Thus instead of a matrix augmented with one column, you'll have one augmented with three.